# Can't Log In After Adding To Path

Tags: command-line, paths

I was trying to add Jupyter Notebooks to the permanent path in linux. I followed these steps:

Open a terminal window using **Ctrl+Alt+T**

Run the command gedit ~/.profile

Add the line `export PATH="$PATH:/media/De Soft/mongodb/bin"` to the bottom and save

Log out and log in again

But I accidentally entered `export PATH=$"PATH:/media/De Soft/mongodb/bin"` where I put the $ in the wrong place. Now I can't even log in to Ubuntu. Am I going to have to completely reinstall? Or is there a way to fix this?

I am able to run **CTRL+ALT+F3** and log in to the shell with my username and password, but I don't know if there's anything I can do from there.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the line you added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can fix it from the shell that you obtained via CTRL+ALT+F3. You will just need to set a new `PATH`, or use the full path to commands until it is fixed.

For example, you can open a command line editor like nano:

```
/bin/nano ~/.profile
```

and correct your mistake from there.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!